# How to calculate and select employees of age above 25 years 2 months from database in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

We have employees of all ages in the database. We need to select only those employees whose age is more than 25 years 2 months.

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify, need to calculate it in days :)

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM emp where sysdate-birthdate>=(SELECT sysdate- 
to_date('19931015','YYYYMMDD') FROM dual);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the months_between function 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm

Oracles own example:

```
 SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN     (TO_DATE('02-02-1995','MM-DD-YYYY'),
     TO_DATE('01-01-1995','MM-DD-YYYY') ) "Months"
     FROM DUAL;
```

> ### Months
>
> 1.03225806

your query would be something like

```
select * from emp where MONTHS_BETWEEN (sysdate, date_of_birth) > ((25*12)+2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ADD_MONTHS` might help, e.g.

```
select *
from employees
where date_of_birth > add_months(trunc(sysdate), -(25 * 12 + 2));
```

- `ADD_MONTHS` adds number of months to the first parameter
- `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` returns today's day at midnight; dates of birth usually don't have a time component.
- the second parameter is:

  - `-`, because we have to subtract months ("25 years ago")
  - `25` - 25 years
  - `12` - a year has 12 months
  - `+ 2` add 2 months